# Oracle PLSQL program to make increasing pattern

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am working on a project, where I come up with a problem, I need a PLSQL program which will execute the following patterns, like increasing numbers, stars, hashes etc.

```
1
12
123
1234
12345
```

Comment: Why does it need to be pl/sql?  As you can see from Barbaros's answer, it can be done with pure SQL.  (You _do_ understand, don't you, that PL/SQL is oracle's procedural language, while SQL is a more-or-less (usually less) standardized _declarative_ language.)

Comment: Please, show the result of your current research and describe why it doesn't solve your problem. SO is not a codewriting service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use such a hierarchical query

```sql
WITH t AS 
(  
  SELECT LISTAGG(level) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY level) AS nr, MAX(level) AS lvl
    FROM dual
 CONNECT BY level <= 5 
)
SELECT SUBSTR(nr,1,level) AS nr
  FROM t
CONNECT BY level <= lvl
```

If needed to be written within a PL/SQL code block, then use a FOR LOOP along with the query above

```sql
SQL> SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
SQL> BEGIN
 FOR c IN 
       (
        <above query>
       )
 LOOP
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(c.nr);
 END LOOP;
END;
/
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=cf3e9bc89d6d64f0768621a963cbc1a3)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

Simply use two loops:

```sql
BEGIN
  FOR i IN 1 .. 5 LOOP
    FOR j IN 1 .. i LOOP
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT(j);
    END LOOP;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.NEW_LINE();
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Which outputs:

> ```
> 1
> 12
> 123
> 1234
> 12345
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=5c7c376f9d978da3ac4482ebea8158ab)*